# LibGDX + Box2D rotation

Tags: c++, libgdx, box2d, simulation

How to apply auto rotation (like in a real world) in Box2D using LibGDX? This doesn't look realistic (see the pic bellow).

[image: Screenshot]

In the real world, the blocks would rotate and fall down, but they don't in this simulation.

The World has Y Gravity at -9.81 (so falling and colliding works fine) This is the code, where I create the boxes:

```
PolygonShape pShape = new PolygonShape();
FixtureDef fDef = new FixtureDef();
BodyDef bDef = new BodyDef();
Body body;

pShape.setAsBox(width, height);
bDef.position.set(x, y);
bDef.type = type;
fDef.shape = pShape;
fDef.density = 1.0f;
fDef.friction = 0.3f;
body = world.createBody(bDef);
body.createFixture(fDef);
body.setUserData(this);
MassData md = new MassData();
md.mass = 5;
body.setMassData(md);
```

Code for the Main Game class:

```
public class Game implements ApplicationListener {

public static int WIDTH;
public static int HEIGHT;

World world;
Box2DDebugRenderer dr;
OrthographicCamera cam;
float time;
final float P = 1/60f;
final static int C = 100;

public void create() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.1f, .1f, .1f, 1.0f);
    WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.8f), false);

    dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH/C, HEIGHT/C);

    new Block(world, BodyType.StaticBody, 2,        HEIGHT,     0,          HEIGHT);
    new Block(world, BodyType.StaticBody, 2,        HEIGHT,     WIDTH-40,   HEIGHT);
    new Block(world, BodyType.StaticBody, WIDTH,    2,          WIDTH,      HEIGHT);
    new Block(world, BodyType.StaticBody, WIDTH,    2,          WIDTH,      0); 
}

public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    input();

    dr.render(world, cam.combined);

    time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    while(time >= P) {
        update();
        time -= P;
    }
}

public void update() {
    world.step(P, 5, 5);
}

public void input() {
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        new Block(world, BodyType.DynamicBody, 50, 20, Gdx.input.getX(), HEIGHT-Gdx.input.getY());
    }
}

public void dispose() { }
public void pause() { }
public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) { }
public void resume() { }
}
```

Code for the Block class:

```
public class Block {

public Block(World world, BodyType type, float width, float height, float x, float y) {

    PolygonShape pShape = new PolygonShape();
    FixtureDef fDef = new FixtureDef();
    BodyDef bDef = new BodyDef();
    Body body;

    pShape.setAsBox(width/Game.C, height/Game.C);
    bDef.position.set(x/Game.C, y/Game.C);
    bDef.type = type;
    fDef.shape = pShape;
    fDef.density = 1.0f;
    fDef.friction = 0.3f;
    body = world.createBody(bDef);
    body.createFixture(fDef);
    body.setUserData(this);
    body.setFixedRotation(false);
    MassData md = new MassData();
    md.mass = 5;
    body.setMassData(md);
}
}
```

Comment: Do your bodies have mass?

Comment: I have printed out their values and they have a mass of 1kg.

Comment: Did you set any gravity? You can also lock rotation for bodies, did you do that maybe?

Comment: Did you give the fixtures a non-zero density? If dynamic bodies are found to have zero mass the engine will set the mass to 1kg, so your mass check may not mean much.

Comment: I have edited the question, so it contains info about creating the box.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can play with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MassData md = new MassData();
```

gives zero rotational inertia: `md.I == 0` so the box doesn't rotate.

If you do

```
MassData md = body.getMassData();
```

you will have mass and rotational inertia according to your current density.

The best way to change mass and get the correct rotational inertia - calculate it by yourself according your new mass, like:

```
float massScale = [newMass] / md.mass;      
md.mass *= massScale;
md.I *= massScale;
```

In that way you'll save right rotation point and have physically correct inertia.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be working, but StackOverflow only alows me to give you the bounty after some period of time (1 hour). So thanks for anwser and be patient.

Comment: Bounty will be a nice addition, but I answered to help you, not for a bounty. Good luck!